# Unzip file in a WinSCP script with SSIS execution script task

Tags: ssis, unzip, winscp

I would like to unzip a remote file to a remote folder and put this script in a SSIS execution process task.

From the following script :

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://user:pwd@myip:myport
cd /var/www/vhosts/folder
#unzip -o test.zip -d /var/www/vhosts/folder1
close
exit
```

The script runs well on Winscp console and in SSIS task - so no connection issue.
But if i remove `#` to run the unzip command it runs from the Winscp console but not with the SSIS task.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `unzip` command in WinSCP. It just cannot work, no matter how you run the script.

You probably wanted to use the [WinSCP `call` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call) to invoke a remote `unzip` command:

```
call unzip -o test.zip -d /var/www/vhosts/folder1
```